# How to use multiple custom dimensions in Google Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to use multiple custom dimensions in GBQ without using the Max function? My problem of using Max function is that it only saves the max pax_num, but I would like to have the count of visitors for all of the combinations of ( Date,product.v2ProductCategory,eCommerceAction.action_type
,product.v2ProductName). Note the pax_num is number of pax on that ticket. I need every combination of the dest+pax_num, not the dest+max(pax_num)

```
SELECT
    Date
  ,count(distinct( concat(FULLVISITORID,cast(visitID as string)))) as visitor
 , product.v2ProductCategory as product_category

  ,max(if(customDimensions.index=2, customDimensions.value,null))  as dest
  ,max((if(customDimensions.index=21, customDimensions.value,null)) ) as pax_num
 ,eCommerceAction.action_type as Action_type

 ,product.v2ProductName as product_name
FROM `table` as t
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hits) AS hit
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hit.customDimensions) AS customDimensions
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hit.product) AS product

GROUP BY 
      Date
      ,product.v2ProductCategory
    ,eCommerceAction.action_type
,product.v2ProductName
```

Comment: Not sure if I understood but when you say you don't want to have the max value of **pax_num** you mean you want all values inside this field to appear in the final result? sort of like having pax_num in the `group by` operation?

Comment: Yes, I would like to have all the values inside this filed. i would like the result be productA-LAS-paxnum5-5 visitors; productA-LAS-paxnum6-6 visitors but right now is  productA-LAS-pax6-11visitors. it takes the max paxnum. I cannot just add the pax_num in the group by because i want to have two customDimensions. let me know if this make sense to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but if you include the field **pax_num** in the group by you might already find what you need, like so:

```
select
    date,
    count(distinct( concat(FULLVISITORID,cast(visitID as string)))) as sessions,
    product.v2ProductCategory category,
    max(if(customDimensions.index=2, customDimensions.value, null)) as dest,
    if(customDimensions.index=21, customDimensions.value,null) as pax_num,
    eCommerceAction.action_type as act_type,
    product.v2ProductName as product_name
from `table` as t,
unnest(hits) as hit,
unnest(hit.customDimensions) customDimensions,
unnest(hit.product) as product
group by
    date,
    category,
    act_type,
    pax_num,
    product_name
having pax_num is not null
```

You gave as an example the pax_num values "paxnum_5" and "paxnum_6". If you insert the value `pax_num` in the `group by` operation, the `count` aggregation should happen on the level of pax_num which would preserve the values (and not mix everything into the `max` value as before).

Also, notice that if you count the distinct combination of **fullvisitorids** and **visitids** you are actually computing the total amount of sessions and not visitors (their definition is not the same).

Comment: Hi Will, I just tried it. when I add the pax_num in the having clause, I get null values for all pax_num. when I remove pax_num from having clause,   the result I got was that I can get either dest or pax. so for example: Dest:LAS, Pax:null or Dest: NULL, Pax:2. but I want to get Dest: LAS, Pax: 2 at the same time. the Pax attribute is not a count or sum of pax, it's just a string value that we record.

Comment: hmm in this case I'm afraid I didn't quite understand what you need. Maybe if you give an example in your question some input that you have and the expected output might help us on better answer what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Add the fullvisitorID solve the problem

```
SELECT
    Date
,concat(fullVisitorID,cast(visitID as string)) as visitorID
  ,count(distinct( concat(FULLVISITORID,cast(visitID as string)))) as visitor
 , product.v2ProductCategory as product_category

  ,max(if(customDimensions.index=2, customDimensions.value,null))  as dest
  ,max((if(customDimensions.index=21, customDimensions.value,null)) ) as pax_num
 ,eCommerceAction.action_type as Action_type

 ,product.v2ProductName as product_name
FROM `table` as t
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hits) AS hit
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hit.customDimensions) AS customDimensions
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hit.product) AS product

GROUP BY 
      Date
      ,product.v2ProductCategory
    ,eCommerceAction.action_type
,product.v2ProductName
,visitorID
```